# CodeIgniter Delete row from datatables involving mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

Hi I am wondering if it's possible to do something like selecting a row within a datatable and have a button "delete" with a method in the controller.

My delete button is to remove the row from the database itself and refresh the page.

This is what my view contains:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#datatables').DataTable();
          });
        </script>

    <table id= "datatables" class = "table">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th> Patient Name </th>
            <th> Patient`enter code here` ID </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class = "list">
          <?php foreach ($patients as $patient): ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?=$patient->first_name ?></td>
              <td><?=$patient->patientID ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

(delete button)
echo anchor('something/delete', 'Delete', 'class= "some class"');

What i want to do is:

Get the id of the selected row in the datatable and pass it to another page in a controller for processing.

Is that possible?

Comment: Something like: `<?php echo anchor('something/delete/' . $patient->patientID, 'Delete', 'class= "some class"'); ?>` ?

Comment: exactly. But the thing is how would i know what row was selected in the datatable. Is that possible?

Comment: Put that button in foreach loop and make one for every row. That you are asking?

Comment: I can do that, but what I'm planning is to do a checkbox for each row then pressing the delete button will delete all the checked row. I personally think that looks better.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using DataTables plugin.  when defining your columns, add a column for checkboxes, like so:

```
        { 
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "", 
            'class':'user_chkbox', 
            "searchable": false,
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {

                var checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' name='user_ids[]' value='" + data.id + "' />";

                return checkbox ;


            }
        },
```

you can get the list of id's to delete by accessing the 'user_ids' post data.

```
$user_ids = $this->input->post('user_ids');
```

you can then in your submit handler function:

```
$this->db->where_in('id',$user_ids);
$this->db->delete('user_table');
```